# How to install two different app on android device using Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I am installing an app on an android device using the following command.

"ionic cordova run android"

but when I am installing another app, it is replacing the old app.

so please tell me the solution so that old and another new app both should be there in android device

Comment: By default it over writes the previous versions

Comment: is there is a any way so that it should not over writes the old app.

Comment: The below answer should work I guess..give it a try

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please check the `config.xml` file, and change the `id` of the app:

```
<widget id="new.app.id" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

That way, it will be considered as a different app and will not replace the previous one.

Comment: After build one app in my android phone, I chang the id in config.xml and try to build another app, but I get the build error: {ERR_UNKNOWN: Non-zero exit code from adb: 1}