# Ionic 2 multiple app

Tags: cordova, deployment, ionic2

Once app is deployed using `ionic cordova run android` it removes another ionic app deployed on the device . Just want to figure out how to deploy multiple apps .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to two different app on android device using ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964527/how-to-two-different-app-on-android-device-using-ionic-2)

Comment: I've added the link of a similar question. Basically, check the config.xml file, and change the id of the app. If the id of the app is different, it won't replace the previous app.